# Regex validation for numbers with comma separator

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

Need a regular expression to validate number with comma separator.
**1,5,10,55** is valid but **1,,,,10** is not valid.

Comment: As a side note - a regex can validate your input, but not parse it (unless you `match` for `\d+`). If your next step is to split the string you might as well split it before validating it. Next, what where does jQuery fit it? Is it a validation plugin?

Comment: Yes I want to validate a string using jquery validation plugin .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

The regex is rather simple: `\d+` is the first number, followed by optional commas and more numbers.

You may want to throw in `\s*` where you see fit, or remove all spaces before validation.

- To allow negative numbers replace `\d+` with `[+-]?\d+`
- To allow fractions: replace `\d+` with `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 13):

Here are the components of the regex we're going to use:

- `\d` is the shorthand for the digit character class
- `+` is one-or-more repetition specifier
- `*` is zero-or-more repetition specifier
- `(...)` performs grouping
- `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of the line anchors respectively

We can now compose the regex we need:

```
^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

That is:

```
from beginning...
|    ...to the end
|          |
^\d+(,\d+)*$              i.e. ^num(,num)*$
 \_/  \_/ 
 num  num
```

Note that the `*` means that having just one number is allowed. If you insist on at least two numbers, then use `+` instead. You can also replace `\d+` with another pattern for the number to allow e.g. sign and/or fractional part.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

---

#### Advanced topics: optimization

Optionally you can make the brackets *non-capturing* for performance:

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

And if the flavor supports it, you can make all repetition *possessive* in this case:

```
^\d++(?:,\d++)*+$
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
^[0-9]*(,){1}[0-9]*/
```

try this

Comment: Well, `{1}` is redundant, and so is the capturing group. This is the same as `\d*,\d*` - it must have a single comma, with optional digits around it; not quite the request here. It accepts `,`, `12,34`, `,34`, and rejects `1`, `1,2,3`.