# JavaScript validation: regex to validate numbers with comma

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I use JavaScript regex to validate numbers like this?

1. 1,000
2. 1,000.00
3. 1000.00
4. 1000

I tried this (the string used should not match):

```
test('2342342342sdfsdfsdf');

function test(t)
{
    alert(/\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d/.test(t));
}
```

but still gives me true.

Comment: I think this has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455988/number-with-comma-separator-validation-regular-expression-is-required

Comment: @Elad I guess it's not the same: her we have a number where comma is the thousands separator, so 3 digits between each comma

Comment: try and give a list of unaccepted values also

Comment: Your regular expression does not test for the start and end of a string!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test if the complete input string matches a pattern, then you should start your regex with `^` and end with `$`. Otherwise you are just testing if the input string contains a substring that matches the given pattern.

- `^` means "Start of the line"
- `$` means "End of the line"

In this case it means you have to rewrite you regex to:

```
/^(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d)$/
```

If you would omit the extra parentheses, because otherwise the `"|"` would have lower precedence than the `^` and `$`, so input like `"1,234.56abc"` or `"abc.12"` would still be valid.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by validate. But this might work.

```
//console.log is used in firebug.
var isNumber = function( str ){
    return !isNaN( str.toString().replace(/[,.]/g, '') );
}
console.log( isNumber( '1,000.00' ) === true );
console.log( isNumber( '10000' ) === true );
console.log( isNumber( '1,ooo.00' ) === false );
console.log( isNumber( 'ten' ) === false );
console.log( isNumber( '2342342342sdfsdfsdf') === false );
```

Comment: With this logic, if you add a value like: `1,,4` it'll pass as True

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var number = '100000,000,000.00';
var regex = /^\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*?(.\d{2})?$/g;
alert(regex.test(number));
```