# Regex to validate comma-separated numbers with optional fractional parts

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript, I need to accept only numbers and commas.

The regex pattern I am using is as follows

```
 var pattern = /^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/;
```

How do I accept commas in the above pattern So that values like `3200` or `3,200` or `3,200.00` and so are valid?

There are similar questions that only partially deal with this:

- [Regex validation for numbers with comma separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455988/regex-validation-for-numbers-with-comma-separator) (only whole numbers with no fractional part)
- [Decimal number regular expression, where digit after decimal is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117024/decimal-number-regular-expression-where-digit-after-decimal-is-optional) (no comma separation, fractional part limited to 1 digit)
- [Javascript function need allow numbers, dot and comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033088/javascript-function-need-allow-numbers-dot-and-comma) (the dots, commas and digits are matched in any order)

Comment: Why not test if the string is a valid number instead of trying to match it with a regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
^[-+]?(?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU3zH2/1)

The basic change here is the addition of `(?:[0-9]+,)*` subpattern that matches:

- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `,` - a comma

0 or more times (thanks to `*` quantifier).

I also used non-capturing groups so that regex output is "cleaner".

If you need to check for 3-digit groups in the number, use

```
^[-+]?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/kU3zH2/3)

Here, `(?:,[0-9]{3})*` matches 0 or more sequences of a comma and 3-digit substrings (`[0-9]{3}`). `{3}` is a limiting quantifier matching exactly 3 occurrences of the preceding subpattern.

Comment: I know it wasn't explicitly mentioned, but I'm assuming things like `3,2,3,6,5,6.2` aren't supposed to be considered valid numbers.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: I updated the answer to meet that requirement. Recently, there have been various similar questions, and there was no such a restriction.